# Open, edit and save image canvas on file.pgm in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

this drawing area to draw image with canvas

```
        Canvas canvas= new Canvas();
        canvas.setHeight(500);
        canvas.setWidth(700);

GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        gc.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        gc.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        gc.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        gc.fillRect(1, 1, canvas.getWidth() - 2, canvas.getHeight() - 2);
```

and I made this method to export drawing canvas to imagem.pgn or snapshot and its correctly

```
public void snapshotCanvasImageToPNG(Stage primaryStage) {

        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter
                = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("png files (*.png)", "*.png");
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);

        File file = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(primaryStage);

        if (file != null) {
            try {
                WritableImage writableImage = new WritableImage((int) canvas.getWidth(), (int) canvas.getHeight());
                canvas.snapshot(null, writableImage);
                RenderedImage renderedImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(writableImage, null);
                ImageIO.write(renderedImage, "png", file);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

and I have many doubts in making these methods to open edit and save the canvas drawing to file.pgm
I made this but it complicate to finish

```
public void openFilePGM(Stage primaryStage) {

    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

    FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter
            = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("PGM files (*.pgm)", "*.pgm");
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);


    File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);

    if (file != null) {
    //doubt here
    }
}

public void saveFilePGM(Stage primaryStage) {

    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

    FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter
            = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("PGM files (*.pgm)", "*.pgm");
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);

    File file = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(primaryStage);

    if (file != null) {
       //doubt here
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you will get to work with PGM images in JavaFX is through ImageJ or [Java Advanced Imaging](http://download.java.net/media/jai-imageio/javadoc/1.1/overview-summary.html) as mentioned by [@VGR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1831987/vgr) or another third party plugin.

Please check [this plugin](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/plugins/pnm-writer.html) that contains code for such IO functions.

And you might also want to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24205382/which-image-formats-does-javafx-support/24255517#24255517) which can show you the formats you can easily handle with JavaFX.

Comment: I believe the [Java Advanced Imaging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/current-142188.html) library supports PBM/PGM/PPM.