# Best way to display scalable graphics as icons in JavaFX?

Tags: java, svg, javafx

I am making a desktop app using JavaFX as the GUI Framework. I wan't my app to scale at any DPI, so I want sharp icons whether the app is run on a 1024x768 or 4K screen. In HTML achieving this is pretty easy with SVG, however I have not found a way to display scalable graphics directly in JavaFX.

What is the best way to achieve this? The app will obviously contain many icons, so I need it to be light and fast. Frankly, I haven't found anything close to what I want searching Google.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24205382/which-image-formats-does-javafx-support? It may help.

Comment: Yes, but looking at this list it doesn't support any scalable format out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a library that you might want to have a look at:
[JavaFXSVG](https://github.com/codecentric/javafxsvg)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to mipa's answer, I have similarly solved my problem using svg2fxml, available here: https://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2012/08/22/svg-to-fxml-converter-as-commandline-util/